# Encrypt password from client side using AES?

Tags: encryption, aes, client-side

I want to encrypt the password sent from client side. I found crypto-js which provides AES implementation. My question is that if i use a "passphrase" for encryption, will anybody who can view the source of the page can also see my "passphrase" too ? If i have the wrong concept please help me clear it.

Comment: You almost certainly have the wrong concept. Passwords are usually hashed, not encrypted. Why do you need to know the password in plain text? Also, yes to your question.

Comment: Have a read: [Javascript Cryptography Considered Harmful](https://www.nccgroup.trust/us/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blog/2011/august/javascript-cryptography-considered-harmful/)

Comment: As ever... you say "I want..." ... I say "why do you want?"

Comment: P.S. To all ye unbelievers... the basic premise of encrypting any data is primarily to prevent any form of snooping, e.g. packet sniffing, being able to read submitted data, which they could easily do (as it will be sent as plain text) if you didn't encrypt it!

Comment: "Client-side encryption allows for the creation of zero-knowledge applications whose providers cannot access the data its users have stored, thus offering a high level of privacy." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client-side_encryption

Comment: I'm using PBKDF2 to store passwords on database. So is it better if i encrypt it at client side using PBKDF2 ? If i do so the hash becomes my password and can be used again isn't it? 
Mine is a small project that's why i don't want to use https.

Comment: @PaulZahra The purpose of encryption in actual usage is to increase the work factor of obtaining the data, hopefully beyond the capabilited or interest of the attacker. 100% security is an illusion, ask RSA or Gemalto.

Comment: @zaph Did you know the Police prevent crime? They don't stop it they 'prevent' it... make it so it takes a computer 17 years to brute force your password... i call that prevention :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot just read the password if it is not stored in JavaScript.

However, in almost any case where the JavaScript code can be read, the JavaScript code can also be changed. And if you cannot trust the code, then all bets are off - the password may be send to or retrieved from anywhere.

Take for instance an internet cafe. You connect to "coffeeplace.com" but you're actually logging on to a hoax service. In that case any unprotected connection can be altered. If the hoax service has obtained a rogue CA certificate then this is even true for HTTPS connections.

If you want to protect a password you should send it over a HTTPS connection. If you want application level security *on top of the HTTPS transport security* then you could encrypt the password using a public key; the server can then later decrypt it with a private key.

Application level security is useful if you want to store the password (hash) securily on your servers for instance. You could then later process the encrypted password using a service in the back-end.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your actual question: Yes, everyone will see the passphrase.

But really, do some research on:

- password hashing: Do you really need to know the plain text of user's passwords?
- why using javascript for crypto is a **really** bad idea in almost all use cases.
- Information security in it's whole

or **please** leave information security to people who know their turf. You are quite probable to introduce new problems, because **crypto is hard**, even with all the best intentions.